# Could anyone care less?

Tags: idioms, american-english

I've noticed recently that where in England we say "couldn't care less" in the US the negative is avoided and the phrase becomes "could care less". This is rather jarring because of the contradictory semantics. Can anyone confirm this observation, and shed any light on the difference of usage (if it indeed exists)?

Comment: yes that link does give a fairly thorough discussion. as i'm new here i'm not sure what to do. should i delete the question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there are lots of Americans who say *"couldn't care less"*. (But also lots who use *could*.) We think of them as synonymous.

Comment: @David: Welcome to ELU. I don't think you should *delete* the question, no. Particularly now someone has answered (which may in fact *prevent* you deleting). I stand by my closevote, but even if 4 others agree and it *does* get closed, it may help future visitors find the original.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thx

Comment: @Peter that is information i didn't have. so an English person in the US would be understood without difficulty. does it sound quaint? this also raises the question of how popular the US usage now is in England.

Comment: @Peter: With your background I suppose that's understandable! Presumably you see it as a kind of "quantum logic" statement meaning *"The extent to which I care is simultaneously all possible values between **not in the slightest** and **infinitely**"*.

Comment: [David Mitchell's Soapbox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om7O0MFkmpw) on YouTube

Comment: @David: this seems the perfect place to bring up one of Weird Al Yankovitch's latest videos, *Word Crimes*, where he says *"I hate these word crimes
Like I could care less
That means you do care
At least a little"*. So not all Americans say *"could care less*. Keep in mind that it is a parody, though. I think *couldn't care less* is still common enough that it's not quaint-sounding (although I'd guess it's in the minority now).

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it sounds contradictory, but:

> - The phrase "I couldn’t care less" originated in Britain and made its way to the United States in the 1950s. The phrase "I could care less" appeared in the US about a decade later.
>
>   - In the early 1990s, the well-known Harvard professor and language writer Stephen Pinker argued that the way most people say could care less—the way they emphasize the words—implies they are being ironic or sarcastic.
>   - Other linguists have argued that the type of sound at the end of "couldn’t" is naturally dropped by sloppy or slurring speakers.
> - Regardless of the reason people say they could care less, it is one of the more common language peeves because of its illogical nature. To say you could care less means you have a bit of caring left, which is not what the speakers seem to intend. The proper "couldn’t care less" is still the dominant form in print, but "could care less" has been steadily gaining ground since its appearance in the 1960s.

- Source: : http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/could-care-less-versus-couldnt-care-less#sthash.0amBO2JY.dpuf